# Load content into div (jQuery), change url, and control from sidebar nav

Tags: html, css, ajax, jquery

Here's my objective. I need to find a plug-in or write a plug-in that does the following:

- On click, loads content from external file or hidden div (with fade-in effect)
- The sidebar navigation will be used to load this content (on click), so it needs to be able to load content into a div outside of itself
- Create a url for the linked content, so I can link to it directly

To cut to the chase, I need it to have all the functionality of Chris Coyier's [Organic Tabs](http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/). I have two pages for you to look at. One utilizes the Organic Tabs and the other does not. The reason I couldn't use the Organic Tabs on the second page is becuase I didn't know how to make it work with content outside of the #tabs div. Maybe that's possible with that plug-in, maybe it's not. Here are the links to the two pages:

1. Page with Organic Tabs: http://ncfic.steadfastdesignfirm.com/events/event.php
2. New page that needs ajax functionality to load content upon clicking an item in the sidebar: http://ncfic.steadfastdesignfirm.com/events-2/overview.php

**Just to clarify, I don't need any help with the first page I referenced.** That was just to illustrate what I want the second page to be able to do, using the sidebar nav, instead of the tab structure.

**Update: Here's a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/taylortsantles/pC2SF/.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Thanks, Taylor

Comment: It sounds like you're searching for solutions for three different problems. Search for each issue here on SO and I'm sure you'll figure out how to do it. Or you could just download the organic tabs plugin and rewrite it to suit your needs.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way for me to use the Organic Tabs, but just make it work for something outside of it's div? My problem is that I don't know how to edit jQuery, so I'm kind of lost when I want to customize something at all.

Comment: Most certainly, hopefully the source code is well documented so you can just rewrite whatever needs changing! :)

Comment: I'm using the Organic Tabs plugin on the other page, currently, and I love it. It has all the functionality I need. I just don't know how to rewrite it to work with the other page, where the navigation is in a separate div.

Comment: Looking at the plugin, it's quite possible that you'll just need to switch around the css from tabs to sidenav-items and it'll work as you want.

Comment: Ok. Interesting. I'm going to take a look at it now and see. There was a wrapper that went around the tab navigation and subsequent <li></li> containers (which held the content). I remember the feature breaking when I removed that wrapper. This means that it wouldn't work in the sidebar nav case, because you couldn't wrap the nav and content together in one div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the UI part out, the jquery implementation could look something like

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    $('#inner').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('#inner').html($('#hidden').html());
        $('#inner').fadeIn('slow');
    })            
})
```

Link to [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/G5qGs/1/)

Comment: Appreciate this helpful answer. Works well, but doesn't accomplish what I need it to. Specifically having the code create a url for each tab that you can link directly to. I also need the jQuery to add a class to the link when it's clicked so that it's clear which tab you're on.

Comment: not really.. This is just a sample of what can be done. check the jsfiddle to see how it can be done in a more generic way http://jsfiddle.net/G5qGs/2/

Comment: As to add class, $('.link').removeClass('active_link'); $(this).addClass('active_link'); in the click function

Comment: This looks promising. The only problem with it is that it doesn't pass a unique url for each div.

Comment: Could this code integrate with the organic tabs code at all? It already has the url feature (http://jsfiddle.net/taylortsantles/pC2SF/).

Comment: unique url? i am assuming to load the page using a ajax call? in that case you can still use the above code.. update jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G5qGs/3/

Comment: View this page: http://ncfic.steadfastdesignfirm.com/events/event.php. Check out the tab links under the image and click on them. Notice how the link changes in the url bar and you can directly link to one of the tabs. This is the same functionality I need. The URL doesn't need to be exactly like that, but you get the idea.

Comment: Ok. figured your issue. organicTab  expects ur navigation to be present within the #tabs container which is not the case in ur code. so may suggestion, add a ID to the table(eg: tabs_table) & use that id in the oraganic tab $("#tabs_table").organicTabs({
        "speed": 150
    });

Comment: I have it working, mostly. I did what you suggested. But my problem now is that when I enter a direct URL to one of the tabs, it doesn't remove the content from the first tab (ie. Overview). The functinality works fine when you click on the tabs in the left. But, when you enter a direct url, it doesn't get rid of the "Overview" tab. I think it's because of this jQuery in the Organic Tabs plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/taylortsantles/JDjsC/1/.

Comment: **Amateur guess:** the jQuery code in that jsfiddle does not work because the nav is no longer above the <li> items that contain the content. If that line of jQuery for the Organic Tabs plugin can be rewritten with the current html (nav outside of the div containing the content) setup, it would work. Make sense?

Comment: I also just updated the original jsfiddle with the full markup for the page: http://jsfiddle.net/taylortsantles/pC2SF/2/. This will help you see the flow of the entire jQuery file. I commented on the part that I referenced in my comment above, saying: "This is what I think needs help".

Comment: Updated the js at http://jsfiddle.net/pC2SF/4/ .. issue was in  "if (queryString[base.options.param])" block

Comment: I was toying with that right as you wrote this and ended up accidentally making it work. :) It's working like a charm. Check it out here: http://ncfic.steadfastdesignfirm.com/events-2/event.php. Thank you so much for your help throughout this process. Good to have it knocked out.